# how i can read n first bit command output in windows batch file?

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, batch-file, checksum

i use checksum command in my batch file and the output of command as follow :

`69514a29dc44cd83b42658e917ed9baf *file.txt`

i want to return checksum only so i should store it in variable without `file.txt` like

CHECKSUM=69514a29dc44cd83b42658e917ed9baf

how i can do this maybe write output of command to file then read this file ??? if yes how i can read just first 32 bits from file and store it in variable ????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a sort of 'left'-function in batch:

```
set str=69514a29dc44cd83b42658e917ed9baf *file.txt
echo.%str%
set str=%str:~0,32%
echo.%str%
```

More info on string manipulation in dos/batch: [Link](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)

Comment: but if i want to store result from command itself how i can do this i try to do `set str=checksum file.txt` but not work

Comment: See: http://serverfault.com/questions/245679/store-output-of-windows-command-in-batch-file