# Store output of Windows command in batch file

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, batch-file

I need to store the output of a command line in a variable. How can I do this?

Comment: Duplicate if [How do I get the result of a command in a variable in windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/108439/12892) from Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Provided a simple batch file `test.cmd` with the contents:

```
echo jscott
```

You can set the output into a variable with the following command line:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %a in ('test.cmd') do SET OUTPUT=%a
```

Used on the command line like this:

```
C:\>SET OUTPUT
Environment variable OUTPUT not defined
C:\>FOR /F "tokens=*" %a in ('test.cmd') do SET OUTPUT=%a
C:\>ECHO %OUTPUT%
jscott
```

Should you want to use the `FOR` within a batch file, rather than command line, you need to change `%a` to `%%a`.

Comment: Your prompt doesn't have `>` for some reason which makes reading the commands more difficult since "C:\SET", for example, starts out looking like a path.

Comment: @Dennis Edited. Sorry about that, should have used copy/paste.

Answer (score 5):

This is how I do this:

```
vol c: > result.txt
set /p DATA=<result.txt
echo %DATA%
del result.txt
```

If result.txt has more than 1 line, only the top line of the file is used for %DATA%.
You could also make result.txt into a variable itself, such as %OUTPUT%.

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the command into something like:

```
command > somefile
```

What you see above sends the output to a named file. If file does not exist, it creates one. Overwrites existing file 
And you can also do this:

```
command >> somefile
```

This appends the output to contents of a named file or creates a file if none exists

See also here: 
[Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb490982.aspx)

Comment: Would you please expand your answer to explain how this stores anything in a variable?

Comment: i want to store output in variable .... and i try this method but it is failed ansd the output of command : `commandline 1>fiel.txt` what is "1" mean ??? and the file didn't creat